# What is required HQL Query that can be substituted instead of "SQL's >=all()"..?

Tags: hql

I need to get correct HQL query instead of the following SQL query.

```
select * from question where qid >=all (select qid from Question where uid = 1);
```

I guess we can not use >=all() in HQL. Correct me if i am wrong.
and also give the correct HQL query for the above SQL Query.

Waiting for Reply... Help.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate supports all operator/expression the way you outlined ..   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions

Comment: i dont see any ">= all ()" example or expression. (However there is ">=" but i dont need this. )..

So can u simply suggest me the exact HQL query for the above mentioned SQL query in my question.